# Maya returning TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, maya

I'm very new to Python and am trying to make my life easier in Maya. I figured I'd try writing simple loops for things I do a lot. For example, resetting all pivots. When I try and run this, I get this error "# Error: TypeError: file  line 6: 'NoneType' object is not iterable #"

```
from maya import cmds

def resetPivots():
    selectAll = cmds.select(allDagObjects = True)

    for obj in selectAll:
        cmds.manipPivot(reset = True)

resetPivots()
```

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

:edit:

As it turns out, `cmds.select(allDagObjects=True)` has a None return value, but you can feed the selection into a list. I've updated the code to this, but I'm stuck again:

```
from maya import cmds

def resetPivots(selection=False):
    cmds.select(all = True)
    selectAll = cmds.ls(sl = True, dag = True)
    print(selectAll)
    for obj in selectAll:
        center=cmds.objectCenter(obj, gl = True)
        print(center)
        cmds.manipPivot(p = (center))

resetPivots()
```

So, I'm getting the coords of the centers of all my objects, but nothing is happening when the lists are passed to `cmds.manipPivot()`

Additionally, is this getting to be too many lines for what I am trying to do?

Comment: `selectAll` value is None. Check why `cmds.select(allDagObjects=True)` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

ive replaced your manippivot to xform and ive filtered your selectAll to take only object with shapes, you can maybe extend to transform or other plugin shapes

```
from maya import cmds


def resetPivots(selection=False):
    if selection:
        selectAll = cmds.ls(sl = True, dag = True, type='shape')
    else:
        selectAll = cmds.ls(dag = True, type='shape')        
    for obj in selectAll:
        center = cmds.objectCenter(obj, gl = True)
        obj_tr = cmds.listRelatives(obj, p=True)[0]
        cmds.xform(obj_tr, scalePivot=center, ws=True)
        cmds.xform(obj_tr, rotatePivot=center, ws=True)

resetPivots()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, it looks like I was using the wrong command. Thank you!